# What is the equivalent of MVC's AuthorizeAttribute in vanilla ASP .NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have just started working with a company that has a web application written in ASP .NET, it isn't using Web API or MVC or Winforms. It is seriously just vanilla, out-of-the-box, raw ASP .NET.

Most of the web Methods looks like this:

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthContext ac = AuthSession.ValidateSession(HttpContext.Current);
    if (ac.HasPrivilege((int)UserPrivilege.KeyReporting))
    {
        XmlTreeBuilder xtb = new XmlTreeBuilder("Root");
        // code to build xml tree goes here
        divContent.InnerHtml = WebUtil.XslTransform(xtb.GetXmlReader(), 
                                                    Server.MapPath("kpiSummary.xsl"));
    }
    else
    {
        divContent.InnerHtml = "Access denied";
    }
}
```

And just to be complete here, the html(ish) portion of the pages look like this:

```
<asp:Content id="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <div id="divContent" runat="server"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

So if this was MVC it would be no trouble at all to refactor the C# code to just stick all of the authorization logic into a reusable data attribute by writing a custom AuthorizationAttribute in order to create code that looks like this:

```
[HasPrivilege(Name = UserPrivilege.KeyReporting, FailMessage = "Access denied"))]
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        XmlTreeBuilder xtb = new XmlTreeBuilder("Root");
        // code to build xml tree goes here
        divContent.InnerHtml = WebUtil.XslTransform(xtb.GetXmlReader(),
                                                    Server.MapPath("kpiSummary.xsl"));
}
```

So I guess the question is "Is this even possible in ASP .Net? If so, how do I go about it?"

I know the obvious answer is "rewrite the entire application in MVC," but that just isn't realistic at the moment. So please don't give me a hard time about my technology stack. I'm just trying to play the hand I've been dealt.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the idea of Activity based Authorization. You can find out more about that [here](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/) with a little further information [here](http://ryankirkman.com/2013/01/31/activity-based-authorization.html).

Basically, the premise is that you don't tie your authorization logic to specific roles defined in Active Directory, but more to activities that can be performed within an application. These activities can be based upon roles or other means you use to control authorisation within your application. The thing is, your code refers to the Activity rather than the specific role.

I've used some of the examples from [this site](http://www.summa.com/blog/2013/11/21/security-in-enterprise-applications-using-mvc-activity-based-authorization) in the past which allow you to create similar custom attributes and apply your authorization logic to that to determine whether a user can access a function or not. This is not MVC (or even web) specific. I've recently used this in a Winforms app to control access to certain functions.